# BATCH File : archive Files per Year with special format

Tags: batch-file, archive

I have a Folder full with files with perticular format (321456.done24) and I want to archive this files with a batch datei per year...that means to create inside this folder an another folder mit the year, if doesnt exist, and all the files from the last years - except the current year- to move them there.
an example that I have found and try to modified :`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FolderIncoming=C:\Temp
set FileMask= *.done24
set FolderSorted=C:\Temp
for %%a in ("%FolderIncoming%\%FileMask%") do (
    set FileName=%%~na
    echo Processing '!FileName!' ...
    set TargetFolder=!FileName:~5,8!
    if not exist "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!" ECHO md "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!"
    ECHO move "%%a" "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!"
)
```

`

but dont know how can I create the folder with year?

Answer (score 1):

With only necessary changes in your code snippet:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "FolderIncoming=D:\Temp"
set "FileMask=*.done24"
set "FolderSorted=D:\Temp"
pushd "%FolderIncoming%"
for %%a in ("%FolderIncoming%\%FileMask%") do (
    set "FileName=%%~na"
    echo Processing '!FileName!' ... %%a ... %%~ta
    rem next tokens and delims valid for 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm:ss' datetime format
    for /F "tokens=3 delims=. " %%G in ("%%~ta") do set "fileyear=%%G"
    echo md "%FolderSorted%\!fileyear!" 2>nul
    set "TargetFolder=!FileName:~5,8!"
    if not exist "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!" ECHO md "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!"
    ECHO move "%%a" "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!"
)
popd
:: some code here
@ENDLOCAL
@goto :eof
```